# Unimplemented API error when running admin.storage().bucket(..).file(..).move() in an emulated Firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

"firebase": "9.0.1" - local
"firebase-tools": 9.17.0 - global
"node": v14.17.4

I'm calling `.move()` using the Firebase admin SDK in an emulated function. Firebase returns the following error:

```
ApiError: file#copy failed with an error - Not Implemented
at new ApiError (.../functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:73:15)
statusCode: 501
request: {
              agent: [Agent],
              headers: [Object],
              href: 'http://localhost:9199/b/public-8s9ch/o/91ff38b1-b521-4a23-8844-b12cffa0ee98%2Fscreenshot.png/rewriteTo/b/private-8s9ch/o/91ff38b1-b521-4a23-8844-b12cffa0ee98%2Fcd665e29-edc8-4832-9bc7-110c21f1e560?'
            },
            body: 'Not Implemented',
```

The exact same code, with the same tests and installed packages, work perfectly when deployed to Firebase instead of being used in the emulator.
The same issue occurs with any call to the storage API regardless of using the Admin SDK or using the client SDK e.g. `.copy`, `.move`, `.delete`, etc.

Here's some code to help with reproducing the error:

```
export const firebaseFunction = functions
.runWith({ memory: "128MB" })
.region("us-central1")
.firestore.document("documents/{docId}")
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    try {
    const { srcId } = snap.data();

    const [files] = await admin
        .storage()
        .bucket('public')
        .getFiles({
        prefix: `${srcId}/`,
        delimiter: "/",
        autoPaginate: false,
        });

    const promises = files.map((file) => {
        return new Promise<void>(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const dst = admin
            .storage()
            .bucket('private')
            .file(`${srcId}/${uuidv4()}`);
            await file.move(dst);
            resolve();
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
        });
    });

    await Promise.all(promises);

    } catch (error) {
    return console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you share your code to reproduce it?

Comment: Sure! I've added it to the original question

Comment: Did you connect the Cloud Storage Emulator as mentioned here https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage?